# Macro for custom schema names doesn't apply in a dbt package

Tags: dbt

I have an issue using custom schema names in a dbt package.

I use the Macro provided in [dbt documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas/#how-does-dbt-generate-a-models-schema-name).

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ default_schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}
```

I put this macro in my dbt package here [dbt package](https://github.com/datafuel/covid-france_dbt/tree/0.0.1).

Finally I use this dbt package in another dbt project [dbt project](https://github.com/datafuel/DataPlatform_docker/tree/feature/dbt-package/dbt_repo/src).

Here is my dbt_project.yml in my dbt project :

```
name: 'covid_france'
version: '0.0.1'
config-version: 2

profile: 'default'

source-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analysis"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
data-paths: ["data"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"  
clean-targets:         
    - "target"
    - "dbt_modules"
```

My dbt_project.yml in my dbt package :

```
name: 'covid_france'
version: '0.0.1'
config-version: 2

profile: 'default'

source-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analysis"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
data-paths: ["data"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"  
clean-targets:         
    - "target"
    - "dbt_modules"

models:
    covid_france:
        stg:
            materialized: table
            schema: stg
        ods:
            materialized: table
            process-airbyte-outputs:
                schema: ods
            unions:
                schema: ods
        prs:
            materialized: view
```

When I try to run my dbt project, it imports the dbt package but doesn't apply the macro that is supposed to remove the main schema prefix (provided in profiles.yml) from custom schema names
For instance : the schema provided in my profiles.yml is "prs". I have other custom schemas named ods and stg. But when dbt run, it create prs, prs_ods and prs_stg.

The macro used to work fine when I use it directly in a dbt project (instead of putting it in a dbt package that I use in my dbt project)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify the problem and add more details, particularly the part of the code that you think is acting out of the expected range. It's not enough to just post links. Thanks.

Comment: I hope it's clear enough. Don't hesitate to tell me what you want me to add. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas#changing-the-way-dbt-generates-a-schema-name

It says:

> Note: dbt ignores any custom generate_schema_name macros that are part of a package installed in your project.

So the way around that would be to create a small "shim" or thin-wrapper directly in your project that calls the macro in your package.

I think it's a bit confusing that your package project name is the same as your actual project name (both line 1 of the dbt_project.yml files), so I would name them differently for clarity.

e.g. assuming you rename the package to `package_project_name`, Use the macro code as you have already in your package, but in your project add another macro like

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

  {{- package_project_name.generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) }}

{%- endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need also to define the target of the jobs, as the macro depends on the target schema.
For example

```
dbt run --models my_model --target dev
```

In a dbt cloud job, you can define as

```
      "settings": {"threads": 1,"target_name": "prod"},
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is still useful for someone. The error on this post's script is that the default schema name is still being used.

So, the final code I believe it should be this:

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}
```

Basically, just get rid of `{{ default_schema }}_` but I'm pretty sure that's not enough. I ran into the same issue a couple weeks ago and I followed the example from this [medium post](https://medium.com/data-manypets/how-to-customise-dbts-model-naming-for-easy-developing-on-production-1238559a939a) but with some modifications and 2 different files.

File 1 (`generate_schema_name.sql`):

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}
    -- check if the target schema is different to dev to use it
    {%- if not target.name == 'dev' and custom_schema_name is not none -%}
        {{ custom_schema_name | trim }}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ target.schema }}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

File 2 (`generate_alias_name.sql`):

```
{% macro generate_alias_name(custom_alias_name=none, node=none) -%}
    {%- if custom_alias_name is none -%}
        {%- set table_name = node.name -%}
    {%- else -%}
        {%- set table_name = custom_alias_name | trim -%}
    {%- endif -%}

    {{ table_name }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

I used them because my main schema is dev/prd, but I have other scripts that are not stored in those schemas, so in my models' scripts when their default schema is not dev/prd (or the one specified in your dot project), what I had to do it's to specify it in the `config` (at the top of the file).

Model that will live in the default schema:

```
{{ config(materialized = 'table') }}

SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM table
```

Model that won't live in the default schema:

```
{{ config(materialized = 'table', schema = 'other_schema') }}

SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM table
```