# dbt call generate_schema_name macro from another project in a mono-repo

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I'm using the following macro that stops using `target_schema` + `custom_schema` in my prod runs using the fabled mono-repo.

target database is snowflake.

```
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

{%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
{%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

    {{ default_schema }}

{%- elif target.name == 'prod' -%}

    {{ custom_schema_name | trim}}

{%- else -%}

    {{ default_schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

{%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}
```

this works in my `core` package (i.e the package that gets imported into my child packages)

```bash
--- dbt_package
  -- models
    - core # my macro is here
    - marketing # this imports core as a package
```

when I call `dbt run -t prod` in `marketing` it falls back to its default settings `target_schema + custom_schema`

however when i run this in `core` it works fine.

in terms of steps

```
dbt deps
dbt run -t prod
```

---

when i check the package that gets imported i can see the macro.

anyone know what my error is or what I'm doing wrong?

#### Edit.

Just noticed that this is the default behavior as per the docs:

> Note: dbt ignores any custom generate_schema_name macros that are part of a package installed in your project.

I can think of a few solutions.

1. create the same macro in every project but this will be a violation of DRY and the whole point of a monorepo.
2. write a custom solution in my CI that creates this macro in each project at run time - still feels hacky.

is there a jinja native work around?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Macro for custom schema names doesn't apply in a dbt package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65588257/macro-for-custom-schema-names-doesnt-apply-in-a-dbt-package)

Comment: @AdamKipnis it does not, it requires one to create the macro manually in each project which in my question above is a violation of dry, especially as the point of a mono repo is to avoid repetition